# How to find a mean probability

Tags: probability

A speaks truth in 75 cases just of hundred while B speaks truth in 80 cases out of hundred.Find the number of cases where they are likely to contradict.
        I did try working it out.So out of 200 cases they will be speaking the truth in 110 cases and will not condradict.So the answer is supposed to be 45.Is this working right.

Comment: You can't look at $200$ cases, you need to look at $10\,000$. Or you could simplify to "three out of four" and "four out of five", and you would only need to analyse twenty.

Comment: How come it's 10000

Comment: Because for each of the $100$ cases for $A$, you need to look at $100$ cases for $B$. That makes it $100\cdot 100 = 10\,000$.

Comment: Where did you get 110? Where did you get 45? Note that they do not contradict if they both tell the truth or both lie.

Comment: Considering 100 cases A speaks the truth in 75 but B lies in 20 so the cases they don't contradict are 55

Comment: You have assumed in that calculation that the $20$ times $B$ lies all coincide with a time that $A$ speaks the truth. This is not correct, because $B$ can lie also when $A$ tells a lie.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming independence:

The probability they both speak the truth is $0.75(0.8)=0.6$. The probability they both lie is $0.25(0.2)=0.05$. The probability they contradict is the probability that one lies and the other tells the truth, which is given by $$1-0.6-0.05=0.35.$$

So you would expect them to contradict one another in 35 cases out of 100.

Comment: Could you please tell me what's wrong in my working